# The meaning of "traveling grate" and "pallet car"

Tags: word-meaning, phrase-meaning

I am writing about an equipment which I just know its English name but not much its meaning (word by word), and I am trying to translate it

the word is **Traveling grate** (e.g by [this company](http://www.outotec.com/en/About-us/Our-technologies/Agglomeration/Traveling-grate-pelletizing/)) in the page they call it as a process,

> Our **traveling grate** process is the leading technology for producing pellets suitable for blast furnace and direct reduction.

while here they say

> After surface ignition on the sintering machine’s **travelling grate**, air is induced through the ignited layer and the process continues in the vertical direction of the material bed.

Then I don't know its an equipment or a name for a process

There is also an equipment named [Pallet Cars](http://caststeelproducts.com/Mining-Mineral-Processing/Pallet-Cars-Sinter-Cars)

I think I can guess their meaning but I am not sure about them (for example why Pallet, why Car! or why Grate, why Traveling).

Grate has many meaning, I guess grate here means a fireplace which is moving
(However it also means a frame of metal bars and the equipment also consists of parallel grate bars)

The technology provide a chain (train or maybe it is called traveling grate) of Pallet Cars to move materials in sintering machine! they are like a pallet moving on rail (maybe because they have four wheel, they named it car), actually pallet has plates which grate bars are on it.

The following is an image of a pallet car consist of 4 plates consisting of parallel grate bars.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

*Traveling*: moving from one place to another

*Grate*: a frame or grid of metal bars (the "fireplace" meaning is not the one you want here - it comes from the fact that a fireplace often has a metal frame as part of it)

*Pallet*: an object, usually wooden, on which you stack other things to make them easy to lift with a forklift

[image]

(Photo by Dbenbenn from [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3AWooden_pallet_with_glove.jpg))

*Car*: You're thinking of *car* as *automobile*, but it can also be used to mean a railway car, a wheeled object that runs on rails as part of a train.  Like this:

[image]

(Photo by William Grimes from [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3A40and8s_style_boxcar.JPG))

Comment: Thank you, the car was helpful, but why they call the machine or the process "traveling grate" and actually the process is about heating materials, then I guessed its a metaphor for a moving fireplace to heat materials

Comment: @Ahmad: That's possible.  This is heading from the realm of general English to technical jargon, which I think is outside the scope of this site - you would need an expert in that particular area to answer.

Comment: @Ahmad If I had to guess, it's called a "traveling grate" because it's like a conveyor belt.

Comment: @Catija yes it is like conveyor belt but why "grate", what means "grate" here

Comment: @Ahmad As Nate has pointed out, it's getting into the technical realms... if I had to guess, I'd think it would be something like [this](http://pre00.deviantart.net/54d5/th/pre/i/2012/031/a/c/metal_grate_by_bardiir-d4o7107.jpg)... which is designed to hold the pellets still and separated as they move through the factory.

Comment: @Catija then for you its net shape and frame form comes to mind!

Comment: @Catija in [one place](http://www.google.com/patents/US3863755) I even read *a traveling grate conveyor*, does the phrase sensible for you.

Answer (score 3):

"Traveling grate" is indeed a technical term. See the Wikipedia article for [grate firing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grate_firing). It does mean a literal metal gate that moves. In this case, the second example you give is referring to the grate itself, while the first example refers to a process involving a traveling grate. The difference is similar to "flying a plane" and "flying **by** plane". The first refers to a plane as a noun, and the second refers to the method of travel involving a plane.

The word "car" is older than automobiles, and in some contexts means basically a box with wheels for transporting things, such as a rail car or the pallet car you reference. It is meant to transport pallets, which are portable platforms made to an industry standard size. They are typically made of wood, to save money, but are sometimes made of metal or plastic for durability. I would imagine in a sintering factory they would be made of metal, both to support the heavy metals and to prevent charring from being near the furnaces.

Comment: Thank you, then it is a traveling grate consisting of pallet cars, and the whole train is a traveling grate because pallets have a grid shape letting air and heat flow through materials.