# Correct usage of "piece"

Tags: word-usage

I wrote:

> Figure 1 shows a single piece pallet car.

Suppose there is a train of pallet cars called traveling grate [you may refer to [this question]](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/63039/the-meaning-of-traveling-grate-and-pallet-car), but I want to point an isolated one which is not in the train to show its structure...

Can I use piece this way? or it is just for uncountable words like *information, equipment...*

My question is actually two parts, one about the usage of "piece" and one about a word for a piece of equipment detached from a bigger structure consisting of several of them.

Comment: I don't understand the question here. A [*single piece pallet*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22single+piece+pallet%22) presumably means a pallet made from one "continuous" piece (i.e. - it can't be dismantled into multiple component parts). So one could apply ***single-piece pallet*** (I prefer the hyphen) adjectivally to a "car / cart" specifically designed to transport such pallets. But where does "uncountable words" fit in? It's logically impossible to interpret ***single** [uncountable noun]* - if [noun] can't be counted, how could you have a ***single one*** of it?

Comment: ...or maybe *a single piece pallet* means a pallet designed to *carry* a single piece. But the same point applies that it must be possible to count anything capable of being modified by ***single***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I modified my question to say what I meant by single piece

Comment: It's still not 100% clear to me what you mean by "single piece". It's obviously not a pallet made from a single piece of material, but it could still be a pallet that carries a single piece of something. On the other hand, perhaps what you mean is ***one*** "pallet car" (a pallet with *wheels*, which could be called a "car" in the context of "rolling stock"). If that's what you mean you could call it a ***single** pallet car* (without ***piece***). Or use any of various alternative adjectives such as ***lone, unattached, solitary, detached, isolated, disconnected,*** etc.

Comment: @FumbleFingers thanks the last adjectives are some I needed

Comment: When I read "single piece pallet car" it sounds to me like "pallet car which is made of a single piece".  I think the phrase you want is just "a single pallet car" or maybe "a detached pallet car".

Comment: Or simply, "Figure 1 shows **a** pallet car".  You could add the word "typical" if you believe your audience is easily confused and needs to have their hands held at every step.

Comment: @stangdon: Could you post that as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the pallet car is the single unit and the train is the composite formed from several units, so you can omit the word 'piece' entirely

> ...a single pallet car ...

Where the larger structure is the normal unit you would need to include the word 'of'

> a single piece (or part) **of** the travelling grate

Remember to include the definite article (the) as well since the grate is countable.
Compare:

> A piece of the puzzle.
>   A piece of chocolate.